# EnumWindows equivalent for Mac OS X (C++)

Tags: c++, user-interface, macos

I'm trying to get a list of the top-level windows that are currently open on OS X. On Windows this can be achieved using EnumWindows and I was wondering if OS X had any sort of equivalent for this? (even having to enumerate through the applications, and then the windows would be fine)

I've tried searching for this, but unfortunately both Google and SO weren't so useful in their results. I think the 'windows' keyword confuses them into thinking I want results about Windows :(

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe not exactly what you want, but here is something from the [Apple Mailing Lists](http://lists.apple.com/archives/AppleScript-Users/2008/Jun/msg00395.html)

Comment: Thanks for the info. It's given me a starting point anyway as CGWindowListCopyWindowInfo sounds suspiciously like what I need.

Comment: That's gotten me a bit closer, however the function returns a list of all windows without regard to whether or not they are top-level windows. I haven't managed to find a way to differentiate between a top-level and child window in OS X. Also the window name returned by CGWindowListCopyWindowInfo does not actually seem to be the window caption, which is annoying.